# Changing tableView Cell Image on selection shows multple selected cell images

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have tableView with Cell Image i want to add selection image when any cell is selected it works fine but problem is that first you select rows one then row one is selected then you selected row2 then row2 along with row1 is selected it should be only row2 selected not both .

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (indexPath.row==0) {


     cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity2.png"]; 
     }

     else if(indexPath.row==1){
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Catalog2.png"]; 


     }
   else{
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Library2.png"]; 

     }

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];

  NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
  [viewControllerArray removeLastObject];
      if (row == 0) {
  self.firstDetailViewController=[[[FirstDetailViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
  [viewControllerArray addObject:self.firstDetailViewController];
  self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.firstDetailViewController;
  }

     if (row == 1) {
self.secondDetailViewController=[[[SecondDetailViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
[viewControllerArray addObject:self.secondDetailViewController];
self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.secondDetailViewController;

    }

   if (row == 2) {

    self.myLearningViewController=[[[MyLearningViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
[viewControllerArray addObject:self.myLearningViewController];
self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.myLearningViewController;
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing for iOS 5.0 and up, you can appeal to [allowsMultipleSelection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsMultipleSelection) if you have this setup well. Set this to `NO`. Otherwise, use [–deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deselectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3a) say to clear the first selection. Call either of these in your implementation of `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: yes i am writing on iOS i want that if user select any cell only on that cell it show selected image which i assign for that cell

Comment: can you please tell me where to use  deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can set cell's background view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *bgView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBgImage.png"];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;
```

And, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, use this

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Please check whether this helps.